# How to Pull Dump of Old News Articles

Tags: bloomberg, commodities, general

My goal is to run a keyword search for phrases like "soybean acreage" or "corn yields" (keywords limited to ag. commodities), and construct a timeline of which dates articles with these key words are published-- obviously filtered by location.

Is there a convenient source where I could download the past 10 years or so of agriculture press releases? Maybe Bloomberg? Or better yet, a site that I could search?

Answer (score 1):

I found a site with a free API that pulls articles from "thousands" of articles:

https://newsriver.io/

Edit: http://eventregistry.org/ is also very, very good.They even have a Python 2.x module: https://github.com/gregorleban/EventRegistry/